# Using Databinding in DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, dependency-properties

I created a class that inherits from `Window` and has got a `DependencyProperty` called TitlebarContent.

```cs
public FrameworkElement TitleBarContent
{
    get { return (FrameworkElement)GetValue(TitleBarContentProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TitleBarContentProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for TitleBarContent.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleBarContentProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("TitleBarContent", typeof(FrameworkElement), typeof(tkWindowControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(FrameworkElement)));
```

Inside a `ResourceDictionary` for Styles i add a `ContentControl`for this property.
Now I'd like to use the new 'WindowObject' in another application and access the new `TitlebarContentProperty`. I can see the items inside my Titlebar and I'm able to move the `Window`, resize it and more. But I cannot bind to these items. For example I'd like to add a Helpbutton inside the Titlebar. The `Button` is shown, but i can't click it.

```xml
    <tk:tkWindowControl.TitleBarContent>
        <DockPanel Grid.Row="0"  FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
            <Button Content="Exit" Command="{Binding ExitApplicationCommand}" Height="60" Width="60" Background="Red"/>
        </DockPanel>
    </tk:tkWindowControl.TitleBarContent>
```

My `DependencyProperty` is a `typeof(FrameWorkElement)` because i like to add several `Buttons` to the Titlebar.

Is it possible to use my Bindings in this way?

Comment: If your button shows up in the UI then I would expect all you need to do is have a public iCommand property ExitApplicationCommand in the datacontext of your window. What do you have at the moment?

Comment: The Background is already  done. I tried the Binding by placing the button in a normal Grid. Everything works. But used in the `Titlebarcontent` the Button has no `IsMouseOver`Effect and the `Binding` doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome` attached property of the `Button` or the parent element to `true`:

```
<Button Content="Exit" WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" ... />
```

Alternatively, you should decrease the value of the `CaptionHeight` property of the `WindowChrome`.

Comment: And again you helped me @mm8. Now i'm done with my UI. Thank you